# How can I configure Editor Tracking in ArcObjects 10.3 for .net for a table programmatically?

Tags: arcgis, arcobjects, arcgis-runtime-net

I use ArcObjects for .net for ArcGis 10.3.

I didn't find any interface to configure editor tracking for a table of GDB database.

How can I configure Editor Tracking for a table programmatically?

I found interface IDEEditorTracking but I didn't find a method to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
         For your reference..first you need to find the dataelement(IDataElement) and then use enable  editor geoprocessing tool..

    IWorkspace pworkspace = ((IDataset)pfeaturelayer.FeatureClass).Workspace;
    IGeoProcessor pGP = new GeoProcessor();
    IGPDataType pGPDataType = new DEFeatureClassType() as IGPDataType;    
    IDataElement pDataElement = pGP.GetDataElement(pworkspace.PathName, pGPDataType);
    IDEEditorTracking editorTracking = (IDEEditorTracking)pDataElement;

    if (!editorTracking.EditorTrackingEnabled)
    {
        //now use Enable Editor Tracking geoprocessor tool
    }
```